# Javascript - Apply() breaking IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have this object:

```
var _intervals = {
    intervals: {},
    _add: function (fun, interval) {
        var newInterval = setInterval.apply(
            window,
            [fun, interval].concat([].slice.call(arguments, 2))
        );

        this.intervals[ newInterval ] = true;
        return newInterval;
    },
    _delete: function (id) {
        return clearInterval(this.intervals[id]);
    },
    _deleteAll: function () {
        var all = Object.keys(this.intervals), len = all.length;
        while (len-- > 0) {
            clearInterval(all.shift());
        }
    }
};
```

For some strange reasons when I remove the `apply()` function from the `_add` property IE9 works, if I leave it there IE9 stops working, but the property `_add` needs that `apply()` to work as supposed.

I researched for issues of `apply()` in IE9 but cannot find anything related.

Any help?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE9 doesn't support passing parameters to the callback through arguments of `setInterval`.

So this isn't a problem of `apply` but of `setInterval`.

You may use this instead:

```
var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2), newInterval = setInterval(function(){
    fun.apply(window, args);
}, interval);
```